# Simplifying $\sum_{i=1}^{b}\frac{b}{b-i+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

The following simplification was used in CLRS:

[image: Equation]

I can see how the simplification works by working through some examples (it effectively reverses the series).

Could someone walk me through the algebraic steps to produce the simplification?

Thanks

Comment: Set $k = b - i + 1$. Then, $k$ varies in $[b]$ as $i$ varies in $[b]$, where $[b] = \{1,2,\cdots,b\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $j=b-i+1$. Then for $i=1,2,\ldots, b$ we have $j=b,b-1,\ldots,2,1$.

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{b}\frac{b}{b-i+1} = \sum_{j=b}^1\frac{b}{j} = \sum_{j=1}^b \frac{b}{j}=b\sum_{j=1}^b\frac{1}{j}.
$$